# Helping out someone related to the field

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I'm a complete layman when it comes to psychology, but I've just thought about this: is it more difficult to help someone who's knowledgeable in psychology and is suffering from mental issues?

PS I wasn't sure as to what tag would best fit the question. Sorry for potentially misusing it.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. I'm sorry if my question was ambiguous. I'm not a psychologist and the situation described in the post does not relate to either me, or any person close to me. I was just curious if knowledge in the field can affect a therapy. If answering "as yourself" on this forum is still a no, I'll be glad to be redirected to scientific research or anything that can be seen as reliable.

Comment: Related to [Why do therapists need therapy?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/26030/7001), [Are psychologists more immune to psychological problems?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16623/7001), and [How do clinicians control for their own mental disorders?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/15866/7001)